# How to use Portal site connection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, administration

Is Portal site connection working in SharePoint 2013? I add another site collection but it seems not showing anything in my navigation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d8546497-f1da-4659-91d2-cf9e7b2a0204/what-does-portal-site-connection-do?forum=sharepointgeneral) (pictures also were credited to this source), you need to enable the breadcrumb in your masterpage for the Portal Site Connection to be available to you in SharePoint 2013.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes - I followed this answer and removed both display:none and visible:false and it still doesn't work. But I think you are right, I need to find out how to show breadcrumb. I wonder if anyone successfully make it work.